# How to approach supervisor not responding to me about my request to work from home?

Tags: communication

A few months ago, I first approached them regarding this issue as it would greatly benefit me to work from home once a week.

They responded with a **no** and their reason was the website currently is unstable and they need me in the office in person to fix it whenever necessary.

Now, the issue has been fixed and the website is fully stable. I sent my supervisor an email to schedule a meeting to discuss if the possibility of my work-from-home request.

It's been two weeks and they haven't responded to the email. Should I talk to them in person?

Comment: I wouldn't advise making a request like this over email. In most workplaces, work from home is a facility, not a *privilege*. Always initiate the request in person (or over phone if the boss works in a different location), and then follow up on email if necessary.

Comment: What does your company policy say about work from home arrangements?

Comment: Hey Zaenille, I've noticed a lot of duplicate questions on your account. To prevent questions from being closed, please be sure to do a thorough search to make sure another post doesn't already answer your question. Duplicate questions tend to spread out useful information across other threads, making it harder for folks to consume, and it also leaves opportunity for duplicate answers, further cluttering the system. Please see [ask] for more details, and [Why are some questions closed?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to address your issue in person but at the right time and with a valid reason. You need to show that working from home will be in the company benefit. If the response is negative, give them other options like working daily an hour extra or something you find more convenient. Try to find valid reasons and options and suggest them to your company. Be well prepared before you address them your request.